# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<GraphQLResult> | Observable<object>'

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

In Ionic application, we are integrating AWS-Amplify and we can able to insert and fetch the data. But while implementing subscription we are getting compiler error says

**Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise | Observable'.
  Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'.**

In Subscription.ts

```
export const onCreateEmployee = `subscription OnCreateEmployee(
  $employee_id: Int
  $employee_name: String
) {
  onCreateEmployee(
    employee_id: $employee_id
    employee_name: $employee_name
  ) {
    employee_id
    employee_name
  }
}
```

In Main.ts

```
const subscription = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateEmployee)
    ).subscribe((eventData) => { console.log(eventData)
    });
```

In main.ts, it shows the error like cannot subscribe ..... (see the above error).

Can anybody know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the result from `API.graphql()` can be both, a `Promise` when you query data for immediate return and alternatively an `Observable` for subscriptions, you need to tell TypeScript what to expect:

```
(API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(onCreateEmployee)
) as unknown as Observable<YourEventDataType>)
.subscribe(
  (eventData) => { console.log(eventData) }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but you can convert Observable to Promise

```
let graphqlCallPromise: Promise<any>;

if(graphqlCall instanceOf Observable) graphqlCallPromise = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateEmployee)).toPromise();

graphqlCallPromise.then((eventData) => { console.log(eventData) });
```

Comment: not working. Same showing error on 'toPromise' and 'then'.

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

you cast it to `any` and get around it

```
(API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateEmployee)
 ) as any).subscribe((eventData) => { console.log(eventData)
 });
```